# Question about Puzzle Creation Etiquette

Tags: discussion

I have created a puzzle that includes multiple steps, that I'd like to post on the site. However, two of the steps use standard puzzles as part of making progress.

> Assuming I attribute the source, is it fair game for me to find an instance of these standard puzzles on the Internet, or use a puzzle generator, and incorporate that into the larger puzzle?

In my case, I'm looking for puzzles whose answers have particular properties that are not necessarily easy to generate from scratch. Many thanks in advance for any feedback you can provide on this question. I want to be careful not to violate any norms that may not be obvious.

Comment: I've voted to move this to Meta, because it's more about site policy, rather than actual puzzle creation. To briefly answer your question though: Providing attribution is the minimum requirement the PSE community puts on you, however, it's still your responsibility to ensure that you have rights/permission/licence to be using any content produced by others. With those caveats in mind, I'd say generated or externally sourced content sounds fine in your given context.

Comment: If it is properly sourced and you have permission to use it, it is *allowed* on the site. But I would say it's bad etiquette, even with citation, to reduce someone else's puzzle to a part of your own. Generated puzzles are more ethically acceptable, but there's another problem. The fact that you *can* use a random puzzle from some other source suggests that these 'steps' are busywork and have little thought put into them. Even if not bad *etiquette*, it sounds like bad *puzzle design*. [...]

Comment: [...] I don't want to do, say, a Sudoku that's mostly unrelated to the rest of the puzzle, giving me a few circled numbers that I use for something else. And I *especially* don't want that Sudoku to be taken from some other source. That's not fun for the solver - it just feels lazy. (I'm not sure whether this example quite matches your case, but that has happened to me before, and it is very disappointing.)